# Requiring packages

Tags: tcl

using init.tcl we have refined the clock command for international use.  This works fine until I attempt to initialize a variable within a package with the clock command. A simple package like:

```
package provide mylib [lindex {Revision: 1.0 } 1]
namespace eval mylib {
    set X [clock format [clock seconds] -format %y%m%d]   
    proc naught {} {
        variable X
        puts $X
        return
    }
}
```

When I run pkg_mkIndex I get:
 warning: error while sourcing mylib.pkg: unknown namespace in import pattern "::msgcat::mcload"

The revised clock command - clock.tcl - uses the msgcat package like: 
uplevel #0 {
    package require msgcat 1.6.1
If I add a puts like puts "PKG: [package require msgcat 1.6.1]" it return empty string not version

Of course clock.tcl is called from init.tcl
I note in the pkg_mkIndex code the following:

```
$c eval {
            # Stub out the package command so packages can require other
            # packages.

            rename package __package_orig
            proc package {what args} {
                switch -- $what {
                    require {
                        return;         # Ignore transitive requires
                    }
                    default {
                        __package_orig $what {*}$args
                    }
                }
            }
```

Which would explain why the msgcat package is not loaded.

### How would I load the msgcat package from the clock.tcl procedure?

Answer (score 0):

All your `pkgIndex.tcl` really needs is a line like this, which you can write by hand (or derive from a template trivially):

```
package ifneeded mylib 1.0 [list source [file join $dir mylib.tcl]]
```

That's assuming that you want your package to use immediate loading. (I always want that for my packages.) You only need to use the tooling to generate an index file if you are using lazy loading, and I don't really recommend that on a package *or application* of any complexity, as it can occasionally trigger weird bugs. Modern computers are fast enough to not need lazy loading (and have been so in my experience for 20 years or more).